# Can you pin a 2D array to a background surface in pygame instead of having it follow the window around

Tags: python, pygame, maze, pygame-surface

is it possible to use a 2D array in order to create a maze block by block but pin each part to the back due to the fact the the background is 2400 x 2400 but the window is only 800 x 800, currently whenever I load the maze it is pinned to the window rather than the background and so follows the sprite around,
Here is the GitHub link to the code so far: [text](https://github.com/homana06/RetroGame)

I looked into using graphs but it seemed to be a lot harder with few advantages another problem i have is that it reloads the maze every time slowing the program down but that should be an easy fix

Comment: You have to include the code as text in the question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276266/how-to-edit-a-previously-asked-stack-exchange-question) your question so we can properly help you. Thanks!